# Android checkbox not removed issue in notes / todo app

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I coded an app which takes notes the eisenhower way.

It is a list view with checkbox and text. If I remove the adapter item the text is removed but the checkbox or the checkbox state remains the same.

You can find the code at github (line 165 in ListActivity.java):
https://github.com/ari-gold-live/eisenhower/

Answer (score 0):

i see the code, `itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
you remove the item from items,but the `itemsAdapter` is not new.

You should use `ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(xxxx);`
`then setAdapter(itemsAdapter)`,maybe it can work.

`notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work sometimes. You should notify the listview by yourself.

Comment: thanks, I think we are going in the right direction, but now the checkboxes are completly empty. i've done this: 

`itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, items);
                            lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);`